# Is docker --cache-from using local or remote registry?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I can't find any information regarding which registry (local or remote) is used when using the docker buildkit `--cache-from` feature.

Let's say I run this:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 
docker build -t my-registry/my-image-name --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 .
docker push my-registry/my-image-name
```

Now, I make some changes to my `Dockerfile` and re-run:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build -t my-registry/my-image-name --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 .
```

but this time I don't push the image on the remote registry, which means the local and remote versions of `my-registry/my-image-name` are different.

Which image will be used for caching when I now run:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build --cache-from my-registry/my-image-name --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 .
```

?